# How to use List data returned from an API call

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Im attempting to get back a list of data from an API call and send this list of data to a local sqlite database I've created for it. I'm getting an issue with the data being a type <List> and I'm not sure how to convert it to something usable. I'm just trying to assign that data from the api call to a variable so I can just simply send it to the sqlite database. Any advice is welcome! Thanks!

This is the code where I'm attempting to get that data from the API call and send it to the sqlite database.

```
if(user.success) {
  Quarter quarters;
  quarters = await getQuarters();
  QuarterDBProvider.quarterDB.newQuarter(quarters);
}
```

This is where the API call is performed

```
Map data;

List<Quarter> quarterFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Quarter>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Quarter.fromJson(x)));

Future<List<Quarter>> getQuarters() async {
  final http.Response response = await http.get(
    'https://myfakeapi/quarters',
  );
  if (response.statusCode < 400) {
    return quarterFromJson(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to get quarters');
  }
}
```

Comment: after calling the API call function. Then use `forEach()` and add each element to the SQLllite DB. In your case it would be `quaters.foreach((index)=> QuarterDBProvider.quarterDB.newQuarter(quarters[index]));`

Comment: try adding `.toList()` after `.map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the response from api is list  and it is not String.

```
List<Quarter> _listQuarter= [];
var json = jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
    json.forEach((element) {
        _listQuarter.add(   -do all your workaround-   );
    });
return _listQuarter;
```

Comment: What do you mean in the do all my workaround? Add it to my sqlite database there?